# Thread synchronization between UI and a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a service that performs some complex automation against 3rd party software (via .NET UIAutomation). The service consists of a host which spins up another STA Thread to run the automation on while the host waits via a `ManualResetEvent`. This was working great until the decision was made to use this in a user-facing environment. At that point, I created an `AutomationMessenger` class to drive status updates out to the UI/WPF app. This worked well. Then at some point, I needed to get and validate user input mid-automation and drive it back down to the automation thread- this is where the wheels have fallen off the bus. I added a call back action to the `AutomationMessenger`, and all seemed well. I ended up shuffling things around a bit, and the user input was needed at a different point in the automation. Ultimately, the methods in the automation classes began to get called twice- So I knew I had some threading issues at play.

Not surprisingly, these issues are not present in testing, or when the service is run without raising user notifications.

The Threads are created as expected and sending messages from the automation up to the UI layer to be invoked by `Application.Current.Dispatcher` works to update the UI, but when a callback action within the automation code/thread is invoked on the UI thread, control is never returned to that thread. I can see it happening in the Threads window in VS.

This is not surprising to me, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

It's taken me some effort to boil the complexity of this code down to a Minimal, Reproducible Example, but I have managed, and it illustrates the issue.

[GitHub - AutomationThreadingIssue](https://github.com/AndyStagg/AutomationThreadingIssue)

I've spent considerable time reading about `SynchronizationContext`s, and I thought that it was going to be as simple as passing the context from the automation thread up to the UI to `Send`/`Post` to it, but learned that worker threads don't automatically get a context.

Simply calling Join() on the automation thread seems to kill the automation thread, or merge it into the UI thread.

Starting a new Task (`Task.Run(() => Callback)`) from the UI thread is the best solution I have at the moment to keep the UI/automation threads separate, but that's creating multiple hits back into some of the subsequent automation methods which respond to windows/dialogs popping up in the 3rd party software (via `Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler`).

After searching for all possibilities of "cross-thread messaging", the consensus is a `BlockingCollection`/`ConcurrentQueue`, or `Channels`. The project is limited to net45, which rules out the channels (minimum requirement is 4.6). And I couldn't get a blocking collection implementation working without blocking execution in the automation thread.

I see a lot of solutions for invoking a delegate/action back on a UI thread from a worker thread, but nothing useful for invoking a method from the UI thread back on a worker thread.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "WPF Thread";

        AutomationMessenger.Received += AutomationMessenger_Received;
    }

    private void AutomationMessenger_Received(object sender, AutomationMessengerEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Name)
        {
            case "Status":
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Status_TextBlock.Text = e.Message;
                });

                break;

            case "UserInput":
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    AutomationInput_Grid.IsEnabled = true;

                    Input_Button.Tag = e.CallbackAction;

                    Status_TextBlock.Text = e.Message;
                });

                break;
        }
    }

    private void Run_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Run_Button.IsEnabled = false;

        var backgroundAutomationTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            var worker = new AutomationBackgroundWorker();
            worker.Begin();
        });

        backgroundAutomationTask.Start();
    }

    private void Input_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Input_Button.Tag != null && Input_Button.Tag is Action<string> callbackAction)
        {
            callbackAction.Invoke(Input_TextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class AutomationBackgroundWorker
{
    private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;
    private Thread automationThread;

    private SynchronizationContext backgroundWorkerContext;

    public AutomationBackgroundWorker()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Automation Background Worker";
        backgroundWorkerContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        automationThread = new Thread(this.Automation);
        automationThread.Name = "Automation Thread";
        automationThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        automationThread.Start();

        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        manualResetEvent.Set();
        manualResetEvent.Close();
    }

    public void Automation()
    {
        var automationSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", "Initializing", null);

        // Initialize Automation Elements, etc..
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

        AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", "Initialized", null);

        // Get user input
        AutomationMessenger.Send("UserInput", "Please Enter Your Name", UserInputCallback);

        // Wait for their response
    }

    // As you would expect, this method is being called from the WPF Thread / UI Thread
    // How can I synchronize it back to the Automation Thread
    private void UserInputCallback(string userInput)
    {
        //if (Thread.CurrentThread != automationThread)
        //{
        //    automationThread.Join();
        //}
        // Doing this blocks and kills the Automation Thread

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput)) return;

        AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", $"Thanks {userInput}", null);

        Complete();
    }
}
```

```
public static class AutomationMessenger
{
    public static event AutomationMessengerEventHandler Received;
    public static void Send(string name, string message, Action<string> callbackAction) => Received?.Invoke(null, new AutomationMessengerEventArgs(name, message, callbackAction));
}

public delegate void AutomationMessengerEventHandler(object sender, AutomationMessengerEventArgs e);

public class AutomationMessengerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Action<string> CallbackAction { get; set; }
    public AutomationMessengerEventArgs(string name, string message, Action<string> callbackAction) : base()
    {
        Name = name;
        Message = message;
        CallbackAction = callbackAction;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract)?

Comment: @rfmodulator That looks promising.

Comment: It's a bit unusual what you're doing. The normal thing would be the UI invoking a background thread (in some way) and that thread executes to completion and, if it needed user input, then it would throw up a new modal dialog box to ask for the input. It's unusual to go back to the original form to get further input. What's the real-world use case here?

Comment: Adding in WCF would be a massive amount of complication to make a complicated thing work. You should look for simplifications of your code, not to double-down on future trouble.

Comment: @Enigmativity the goal is to keep the UI (modals, etc) out of the automation code. Unlike the example, it's in a non-UI library, and I don't want to bring up a dialog or modal from it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, that asking for a string input is simply an example. The inputs range from simple acknowledgments of certain parameters (an "OK" button) to more complex selection dialogs which can't be determined before the automation begins.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here- I was hoping a thread-savvy person would offer an easy solution. And I still hope they appear. I gave the back story of the service in hopes to avoid the "code it differently" responses. The current-day code evolved to be what it is based on the requirements at the time. My intention is to keep a clean separation between the automation code, and any UI / user interaction code, as it's equally important to maintain the original purpose of the automation codebase.

Comment: @AndyStagg - You need to allow the automation to drive the UI to collect the user input. It can't come from the UI that calls the automation.

Comment: "My intention is to keep a clean separation between the automation code" - it sounds like you're doing the opposite. Your code example shows a strong, bi-directional dependency.

Comment: And in saying that out loud, I might try to include an interface, which will allow the automation layer to bring up UI dialogs, as provided by the UI layer, but I'm not sure how that shakes out thread wise.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I don't disagree that there is strong bi-directional dependency when the automation is run from a user-facing environment, but these issues were only introduced when that became a requirement (despite my objection). I am just trying to make this work.  I can guarantee that boiling things down to the MRE is missing an unexplainable amount of complexity in the automation. Rewriting the automation is off the table / not in scope.

Comment: These things are off the table until the technical debt is finally evaluated - either voluntarily or by complete project failure. I wish you good luck.

Comment: 1. why don't you propose an automation service with a clear "talk" interface ? 2. why don't you stack tasks in order to achieve this (first task called by UI, others are started and awaited from the first task) ? 3. if you insist on using threads, for thread sync and pool management, you got semaphores, mutexes, etc why not using them when they are designed to help ?

Comment: Also 4. Your Automation worker AutomationMessenger should be separate services, and the Automation should not have any responsibility in terms of UI; your whole design can be a lot simplified and then you could do everything from the UI thread and with tasks, and avoid completely any thread management (if any, this should go to the Automation and only it). You don't need semaphores and such. Unless your service is actually doing more for more many UIs.

Comment: @Soleil I think the MRE project might be deceiving.

Comment: @AndyStagg Does this mean that you won't work on it anymore ?

Comment: @Soleil - Correct, the answer I provided solves the issue I was facing. I don't see any reason to improve an MRE which intentionally stripped out the actual UI, services, base classes, the actual automation itself, etc... to highlight the thread synchronization issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending most of the day trying to implement a custom `SynchronizationContext`, and being fairly successful in that, I stumbled into a way of making a `BlockingCollection<T>` work for my needs.

TL;DR for the posts which suggest using a `BlockingCollection<T>` to ensure `Actions`/delegates/methods are run on one thread, here is a boiled down (you need to add your own error handling) example:

**PoorMansSynchronizier** aka `AutomataionActionQueue`.

```
public class PoorMansSynchronizier
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Action> _queue;
    private readonly Thread _thread;

    public PoorMansSynchronizier(Action<Thread> options)
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

        _thread = new Thread(() => Execute());

        options?.Invoke(_thread);

        if (!_thread.IsAlive) _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action) => _queue.Add(action);

    public void Complete() => _queue.CompleteAdding();

    private void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var action in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated Background Worker Service**

```
public class AutomationBackgroundWorker
{
    private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;
    private PoorMansSynchronizier poorMansSynchronizier;

    public AutomationBackgroundWorker()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Automation Background Worker";

        poorMansSynchronizier = new PoorMansSynchronizier(thread =>
        {
            thread.Name = "Automation Thread";
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        });

        manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        poorMansSynchronizier.Invoke(() => Automation());
        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        manualResetEvent.Set();
        manualResetEvent.Close();

        poorMansSynchronizier.Complete();
    }

    public void Automation()
    {
        AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", "Initializing", null);

        // Initialize Automation Elements, etc..
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

        AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", "Initialized", null);

        // Get user input
        AutomationMessenger.Send("UserInput", "Please Enter Your Name", UserInputCallback);

        // Wait for their response
    }

    private void UserInputCallback(string userInput)
    {
        poorMansSynchronizier.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // Do something with the response
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput)) return;

            AutomationMessenger.Send("Status", $"Thanks {userInput}", null);

            Complete();
        });
    }
}
```

The key here is, that the poor man's synchronizer has its own `Thread`, and its purpose is to execute each item on the queue.

I was able to do away with the background worker having to hold a reference to the old `automationThread` in the original question code, and now any action I need to run on the STA automation thread, I just pass to the queue.

This has no effect on the original implementation of the non-user-facing automation code- As far as it knows, it's still running on an STA thread named Automation Thread, and it's as happy as it was before the user-facing requirements were implemented- No doom and gloom or crippling technical debt that only a giant refactor of the automation code could solve @Enigmativity.

Comment: By definition a refactoring does not change your functionality.